# Convert to hierarchical structure

Tags: javascript

```
var sample = [{
        "_id": "1",
        "category": "type1",
        "path": "data1//data2//data3//data4",
        "org": "001"
    },
    {
        "_id": "2",
        "category": "type2",
        "path": "data1//data2//data3//data4",
        "org": "002"
    }
];
```

Above sample data needs to be convert into hierarchical structure.

```
var sample = {
    children: [{
            name: "type1",
            children: [{
                name: "data1",
                children: [{
                    name: "data2",
                    children: [{
                        name: "data3",
                        children: [{
                            name: "data4"
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        },
        {
            name: "type2",
            children: [{
                name: "data1",
                children: [{
                    name: "data2",
                    children: [{
                        name: "data3"
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }

    ]
};
```

Expected output:

```
+type1
  data1
    data2
      data3
        data4
```

Comment: What have you tried? You need to provide the code that didn't work before we can help you. If you haven't tried something do some research into looping and creating objects and come back when you have a specific question.

Comment: please help anyone how to convert flat data to hierarchical structure

Comment: Welcome to _StackOverflow_! Here, you can learn [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) properly before you do so. When asking a question, be sure you are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and always try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when possible. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table and a hierarchical structure for assigning the sublevels of the nested structure with a possibility of an access via category or path values.

Basically this proposal check for a key and if not in the object, then a new  object with a single property and an array for the children is created, as well as a new object is puished to the parent underscore array with the same reference to the array of the former created array.

Then the actual level is returned. At the end an objetc is created with lanst value and pushed to the array.

```js
var sample = [{ _id: "1", category: "type1", path: "data1//data2//data3//data4", org: "001" }, { _id: "2", category: "type2", path: "data1//data2//data3//data4", org: "002" }],
    result = { children: [] };

sample.forEach(function (a, i) {
    var keys = [a.category].concat(a.path.split('//')),
        last = keys.pop();

    keys.reduce(function (r, k) {
        if (!r[k]) {
            r[k] = { _: [] };
            r._.push({ name: k, children: r[k]._ });
        }
        return r[k];
    }, this)._.push({ name: last });
}, { _: result.children });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```